# PageView disable multitouch swipe

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview

When swiping PageView with multiple fingers multiple pages are often swiped. I don't think it's entirely deterministic but when swiping with one finger it always swipes to next/previous page. When with two or more it often swipes 2-3 pages away. 
Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

```dart
PageView.builder(
      controller: pageController,
      onPageChanged: (index) { ... },
      itemBuilder: (context, position) { ... }
);
```

**Edit:** 
I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56037327/775076) but it doesn't work. Seems like adding more fingers to swipe makes pages move faster even when only first pointer is rejected, which is strange.

Comment: To get help you will have to share the code involved in your question.

Comment: There is nothing special about my code. It's just PageView.builder without anything custom.

Comment: Even so. It's standard to share your code when asking for help with code issues. It also helps user visualise what you want to achieve.

Comment: ok, I edited my post - thanks

Comment: @Brazol, did you find the solution?